# create sub type of case class in scala

Tags: scala, case-class

I want to create sub types of case class Grp like `GrpA` `GrpB`.

Case class inheritance is not possible.
  Any suggestion to create its sub type.

```
trait Value

// define these in different files if you want
case class Student(value: String) extends Value
case class Employee(value: Double) extends Value
case class Department(value: Int) extends Value

case class Element(key: String, value: Value)

case class Grp (elements: List[Element] = Nil) extends Value {
  def add (key: String, value: Value): Grp = Grp(this.elements ++ List(Element(key, value)))

}

Grp()
  .add("2", Student("abc"))
  .add("3", Employee(100.20))
  .add("4", Department(10))
  .add("5", Grp().add("2", Student("xyz"))) // nested group
```

Comment: Make `Grp` a regular class

Comment: @Dima any way to make use of trait and create sub class types of `Grp`

Comment: Sure. `trait Grp; class GroupA extends Grp` etc.

Comment: I am not sure about add method

Comment: make sure then ...

Comment: I mean I not sure how to override add method as it calls Grp again.I want to have sub type of Grp as `GrpA` and `GrpB`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152463/discussion-between-coder25-and-dima).

Comment: U mentioned it `GrpA` as class not case class any reason

Comment: The reason is mentioned in your question - there is no inheritance between case classes.

Comment: How to override  add method .it is a common functionality  and it calls Grp

Comment: You'll have to implement it in each subclass. You can make a utility in the super-class like `def addelem(k: String, v: Value) = elements :+ Element(k,v)`, and then the subclasses would need to still have `def add(k: String, v: Value) = copy(addelem(k,v))`. There is no way around it other than reflection.